# Zend Framework appendFile not working after jQuery include

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, appendfile

I'm setting a local path for jQuery in my layout. Then adding another js file using appendFile, but it's not adding the file I'm appending.

### **in layout:**

```
$jquery=$this->jQuery();
$jquery->enable(); // enable jQuery Core Library
$jquery->setLocalPath($this->baseUrl().'/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js');
echo $jquery;
echo $this->headScript();
```

### **In my view:**

```
$this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl().'/js/jquery.corner.js');
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the following line in your action, instead of your view:

```
$this->view->headScript()->appendFile($this->view->baseUrl().'/js/jquery.corner.js');
```

The line `echo $this->headScript();` is being executed before any of your view code is, so it won't take your `appendFile()` statement into account. If you put it in your action, the action code is called before the layout and view are rendered, so it will take it into account.

Comment: That's not working either. I think it's an issue with how jQuery is added. If I don't use "$jquery->setLocalPath" , then zend will try to include it from Google code. But I'm using a local copy of jQuery.

Comment: appendFile is not related to the location the library is loaded. As mentioned, your issue is to do with the load order - your appendFile call should be in an action, not a view. 

Why should you be including a js file in a different place from your layout in any case? 

Also, the same logic regarding action vs view applies to enabling jquery & setting the path in the layout - this should be in your bootstrap or action?